# HttpServletRequest attributes are lost when propagating from within iFrame

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, iframe, web-applications

My webapp has an iframe-based testing and what I can see (when browsing through iframe) is the following:

1) When I set an HttpServletRequest session attribute on a JSP, for firefox it is capturing/preserving as expected.

`request.getSession().getAttribute("myAttr") // returns what I want`

2) I move between pages and check the above using debugger, I can confirm that the behaviour is okay.

3) When I use Chrome, I can no longer see the request session attributes in the consecutive requests:

`request.getSession().getAttribute("myAttr") // Returns NULL`

I have traced this via the input Filters (defined in my `web.xml`) and all the session attributes are actually lost as soon as a new request is made. This only happens for Chrome and IE, not firefox and Opera.

From the look of things, it seems to me that for Chrome/IE every request is being prepared and sent by cleaning up all the session attributes. But to me this appears to be a browser specific problem. Also, I am sure there is a simple explanation for this, but cannot remember what this is.

BTW - All the browsers work totally fine when not done from within iFrames.

Could someone please me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, this is due to the cookies being blocked from my iframe site. So as soon as I whitelisted the site it worked fine!!

Is this is an expected behaviour? Since firefox and Edge doesn't have the issue? I mean, I don't have to do the same for Firefox and Edge and they work as it is.